# failureUrl and failureForwardUrl not working

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

1. Failed login attempts displays the login page (.loginPage("/signin")) instead of .failureUrl("/signin-error").
2. When application starts, displays an empty page (with words $END$) instead of login page ('/signin').

Spring Security 4

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jpaAccountService")
    private AccountService accountService;

          public void  configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

            auth
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

          }

        @Override
         public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
             web
                 .ignoring()
                     .antMatchers("/resources/**");
         }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new DefaultRequiresCsrfMatcher())
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .loginPage("/signin")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
                    .failureUrl("/signin-error")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/secure")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer())
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/signout")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/signin")
                    .and()
                    .rememberMe()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**","/register").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .invalidSessionUrl("/")
                    .maximumSessions(1);

        }
         private static final class DefaultRequiresCsrfMatcher implements RequestMatcher {
                private Pattern allowedMethods = Pattern.compile("^(GET|HEAD|TRACE|OPTIONS)$");
                private RegexRequestMatcher unprotectedMatcher = new RegexRequestMatcher("/connect/yahoo", null);
                /* (non-Javadoc)
                 * @see org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher#matches(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
                 */
                @Override
                public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
                    if(allowedMethods.matcher(request.getMethod()).matches()){
                        return false;
                    }

                    return !unprotectedMatcher.matches(request);
                }
            }
         @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
         @Override
         public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
             return super.authenticationManagerBean();
         }   

         @Bean(name="userDetailsService")
         @Override
         public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return new RepositoryUserDetailsService(accountService);
        }

        @Bean
        public SocialUserDetailsService socialUsersDetailService() {
            return new SimpleSocialUsersDetailService(userDetailsService());
        }

        @Bean
        public UserIdSource userIdSource() {
            return new AuthenticationNameUserIdSource();
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
        }
        @Bean
        public TextEncryptor textEncryptor() {
            return Encryptors.noOpText();
        }

    }
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signin")
        public String signin(Model uiModel){
            uiModel.addAttribute("signupForm", new RegistrationForm());
            return "signin";
        }

    @RequestMapping("/signin-error")
    public String loginError(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("loginError", true);
        uiModel.addAttribute("signupForm", new RegistrationForm());
        return "signin";
    }
```

Login Form

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">


    <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
        <h1>Logged In</h1>
    </div>

    <div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
        <p th:if="${loginError}" class="error">Wrong user or password</p>
        <div id="login">
            <form name="loginForm" th:action="@{/authenticate}" method="post">
                <table>
                    <caption align="left">Login:</caption>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email Address:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" value=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password:</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/></td>
                     </tr>
               </table>

                 <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

           </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to use failureForwardUrl instead of failureUrl

Comment: I tried that also..

Comment: Try to place the authorizeRequests before formLogin

Comment: That wroks. No. 2?

Comment: I'm not sure that i understood, if you place the authorizeRequests before formLogin it do works?

Comment: Great, I'll appreciate if you'll mark my answer as answered.

Comment: Let me know if you need more help ;-)

Comment: Did it work for you??

Comment: Can you explain better what are you trying to achieve in #2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ensure .authorizeRequests() block comes before .formLogin() (as suggested by @MosheArad). Then replace '.defaultSuccessUrl("/secure")' with '.successForwardUrl("/")'.
2. There was an index.jsp in the root directory, which was taking precedence over the mapping defined in Controller. After deleting this file the redirect started to work.

Answer (score 2):

From Spring Documentations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class FormLoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER").and().formLogin()
                            .usernameParameter("username") // default is username
                            .passwordParameter("password") // default is password
                            .loginPage("/authentication/login") // default is /login with an HTTP get
                            .failureUrl("/authentication/login?failed") // default is /login?error
                            .loginProcessingUrl("/authentication/login/process"); // default is /login
                                                                                                                                            // with an HTTP
                                                                                                                                            // post
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
```

}

**Try to place the authorizeRequests before formLogin**

**In order to achieve that:**

> When application starts, displays an empty page instead of login page
>   ('/signin').

First, override this method:

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web)
               throws Exception
```

within your security configuration file, and use the `ignoring()` in order to tell your security mechanism which pages to be ignored security wise.

Example from Spring Docs:

```
webSecurityBuilder.ignoring()
 // ignore all URLs that start with /resources/ or /static/
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**");
```

In that ignoring() you can write an ant matcher to your black page.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/");
}
```

In your controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String signin(Model uiModel){
        uiModel.addAttribute("signupForm", new RegistrationForm());
        return "signin";
    }
```